# What improvements are needed in this class to fill DropDown using PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Below is the class which I am using to fill multiple DropDowns on ASP.NET Page Load event:

```
public sealed class getBlocks
{
    public getBlocks(DropDownList dropDownName, string districtId)
    {
        returnBlocks(dropDownName, districtId);
    }

    public void returnBlocks(DropDownList DropDownName, string DistrictId)
    {
        var DB = new PetaPoco.Database("cnWebDems");
        string Query = "SELECT distinct blockname, blockid FROM hab_master WHERE distid = '" + DistrictId + "' ORDER BY blockname";
        var result = DB.Fetch<hab_master>(Query);
        DropDownName.DataSource = result;
        DropDownName.DataTextField = "blockname";
        DropDownName.DataValueField = "blockid";
        DropDownName.DataBind();
        DropDownName.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
        DB.Dispose();
    }
```

Suggest further improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, data access should be separate from your UI logic. Certainly create a new layer, where you'll manage CRUD operations.

Secondly, I'm not really fond of your naming convention of classes. Even though it may be a subjective matter, many people tend to use capitalized names for classes and certainly not using words like "getBlocks". This isn't a name for a class, that's a name for a getter method.

Thirdly, you're dealing with your parameters the wrong way, at least in my opinion. I believe it would be more appropriate to have private fields of type DropDownList and String, populate them in the constructor and then just use these private variables (and/or properties, depends on your needs) instead of specifying parameters for the method itself. Seems more OOP to me that way. Otherwise I don't really see a reason why not just create a helper class with a static method you'll call whenever needed, without the need to instantiate the class itself.

Another thing to consider - usually it's better to use an `using` statement instead of manually calling `Dispose` method.

**Edit** based on the comment:

1.) example using private fields

```
public sealed class Blocks
{
    private DropDownList _ddList;
    private int _districtId;

    public Blocks(DropDownList dropDownList, int districtId)
    {
        _ddList = dropDownList;
        _districtId = districtId;
    }

    public void PopulateDropDownList()
    { 
        var results = MyDbAccessClass.GetBlocks(_districtId); 

        _ddList.DataSource = results;
        _ddList.DataTextField = "blockname";
        _ddList.DataValueField = "blockid";
        _ddList.DataBind();
        _ddList.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
    }
}
```

2.) example using static method

```
public sealed class MyHelperMethods
{
    public static void PopulateWithBlocks(DropDownList ddList, int districtId)
    {
         var results = MyDbAccessClass.GetBlocks(districtId); 

        ddList.DataSource = results;
        ddList.DataTextField = "blockname";
        ddList.DataValueField = "blockid";
        ddList.DataBind();
        ddList.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea...

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Can you please illustrate third point with little code.

Comment: @RPK, please see the updated answer with examples. Hope it helps.

Comment: I avoid static methods because they create problems in a concurrent environment. Will your static method work in such environment?

Comment: Static variables are dangerous in asp.net, that's true, but static methods should be perfectly ok, especially helper methods like this. I've been using similar methods in asp.net on various shared webhostings without any issue for quite some time. If you're working with some kind of multi-thread application or with an application with its data being constantly edited by multiple users, you still need to apply some lock mechanism that will prevent possible problems with deleting, inserting and updating the data.

Comment: To be honest though, the shown method is used just for retrieving some data and populating the dropdownlist with some values. I'm not sure how would that be a problem in any asp.net environment, because every request creates a new aspx page, with a new set of controls etc, so instances won't affect each other like it would be in the scenario with static variables. Either way, you don't have to do it if it causes you any problems or discomfort, you can use the first approach with instance variables and adapt that code to your needs. ;-)

Comment: I faced an issue with static methods used to populate GridView. At certain intervals, the GridView started showing results of another user's DropDownList. I didn't get any solution yet. SQL Server service needs to be restarted to correct the problem. This problem occurred each time many users were connected.

Comment: @RPK, not sure what caused your problems back then, maybe you should post that code in another question, but I've made some research on the Google and made some tests by myself, resulting in the same answer - `static methods` aren't a problem unless you use `static variables`. Static methods are thread-safe. The biggest issue about static methods is unit testing, but that's a different matter... If your GW started to show results of another user's ddlist, it implies you used static members/variables/properties, but the method itself probably wasn't the problem...